# Updating the score label in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, image, if-statement, swiftui, shuffle

my issue is that i am unable to get my score label to update properly. I am trying to add +1 when there is a correct selection of an image. However it will only update occasionally which i believe is down to the randomness of the array but i'm not sure. I have tried to change the values or how things are randomised but it wont play ball or effects the desired functionality of the game. I think this is one of those things where i have been staring at it too long. Thanks in advance!

```
@State private var targetArray = ["Target1", "Target2", "Target3", "Target4", "Target5", "Target6", "Target7", "Target8", "Target9", "Target10"]

@State private var MainTarget = Int.random(in: 0...5)
    @State private var numbers = Array(0...5).shuffled()
    @State private var score = 0

 func buttonAction() {

        // randomise the images
        targetArray.shuffle()

        numbers.shuffle()

        self.MainTarget = Int.random(in: 
 0...self.numbers.count - 1)

        // correct target selected
        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[0] {
            self.score += 1 }
        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[1] {
            self.score += 1 }
        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[2] {
            self.score += 1 }
        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[3] {
            self.score += 1 }
        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[4] {
            self.score += 1 }
        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[5] {
            self.score += 1

        } // wrong target selected. Add game over
        else { self.score -= 1
        }

    }
```

Comment: I should have also added my array ends with . shuffled()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just incase anyone is interested for the future i have solved the issue by instead of randomising my array ect every time a button is pressed it will now check for the win condition first separately on each button then randomise and update score label.

```
  self.buttonAction()
                        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[0] {
                            self.score += 1 } else { self.score -= 1 }
                        // randomise the index position and index chosen
                        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[0] {
                            self.numbers.shuffle(); self.MainTarget = Int.random(in: 0...self.numbers.count - 1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I'm getting your question right. But it looks like, as you can simply replace your if-statements with the following code (it doesn't matter which element in the array is equal to MainTarget, because you add 1 to the score variable, regardless of which number matches with MainTarget):

```
if numbers.contains(self.MainTarget) {
    score += 1
} else {
    score -= 1
}
```

The problem with your code is, that you will always decrease your score-variable by 1 execpt for the scenario the last if-statement is true. So if your first condition is true, you add 1 to score, but in the end you will decrease score by 1, because your last if check will fail...

EDIT: There might be even some logical issues, because numbers will always contains MainTarget, since MainTarget is between 0 and 5 and numbers contains all numbers from 0 til 5...

Comment: Thank you for you're reply finebel. I should have been more specific, it does matter which element is equal to MainTarget because i need it to be able to tell the difference between a right and wrong answer. I tried you're code and you are right it did just +1 no matter what because MainTarget is 0...5 and numbers is 0...5.